# Iterating over a two lists of integers in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm coding a function to produce [image: Lagrange Interpolation], being [image] expression.

Given two lists: `Xs` and `Ys` and so `x` I wrote the algorithm below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf8 
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
import json

L = {}
x = Symbol('x')
expresion = ''
def lagrange(Xs, Ys, x):

    for k in len(Xs):

        if k != 0 or k != len(Xs)-1: #si no es el primero o el último término de la sumatoria
            expresion = expresion + '+' + Ys[k] + '*'
        elif k==0:
            expresion = expresion + Ys[k] + '*'
        for i in len(Xs):
            if k==i:
                continue # Si i==k saltamos esta iteración para eliminar división sobre cero
            expresion = expresion + '(' + '(' + x + '-' + Xs[i] +' )' + '/' + '(' + Xs[k] + '-' + Xs[i] + ')' +')'
    print simpify(expresion)
```

When I ran:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf8 

from lagrange import *

lagrange([0,1,2,4],[-1,0,7,4,63],3)
```

I got:

```
[......]line 12, in lagrange
    for k in len(Xs):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

So how should I iterate over `Xs` and `Ys` elements and so include condition that if `i=k` it will `continue` over the loop?

Comment: `for k in range(len(Xs))`?

Comment: You don't need to implement this yourself, it's already been done: [`scipy.interpolate.lagrange()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for k in range(len(Xs))
```

Will give you all the possible indicies in Xs.

`len(Xs)` simply returns an `int`, which is not iterable. You would want to do the same for your `i` loop.